# cakephp: redirect back to initial request after login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I implemented security according to this tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

What I want it to do is if a user issues a request and isn't logged in, they are presented with the login page and then redirected back to their original request.

I think I need to add code in app_controller.php (the top level controller) to save the initial request as maybe a session variable, and then add a line at the end of this function in the users controller to redirect to the saved value:

```
function login() {
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
            // redirect to referrer here
        }
    }
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I can't copy-paste you now the solution, but what you say is what you have to do: save in the beforeFilter the referer page, and redirect to the referer after login. You must watch for avoiding infinite redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a quick search... [Take user back to previous page after logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795430/take-user-back-to-previous-page-after-logging-in)

Answer (score 0):

So from dogmatic's linked thread, it looks like all I needed to do is replace this line from the tutorial:

```
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'alerts', 'action' => 'index');
```

with this:

```
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'alerts', 'action' => 'home');
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've spent enough time with CakePHP to do steps below. Here is the solution;

1. Add the `Auth` and `Session` components to AppController's components (if you
   haven't done). From now on all of your controllers able to use of
   Auth and Session functions.
2. Override the `beforeFilter()` function of the `UsersController` (or similar controller
   to manage user actions) with that one-line-of-code;
   `$this->Auth->loginRedirect = $this->Session->read("Auth.loginRedirect");`
   This
   code should be placed into function since PHP doesn't support function calls into
   variable assingment.
3. After that, to prevent mistaken redirection to already redirected pages, also add that line to the
   `UsersController`'s `beforeFilter()` function;
   `$this->Session->write('Auth.loginRedirect', "/");`
   The above code is not required if you sure that done step 4 for every controller.
4. Override the `beforeFilter()` function of
   the controller that you wanted to get back there after login with
   that one-line-of-code;
   `$this->Session->write('Auth.loginRedirect', Router::url(null,
   true));`.
   What this code does is simply writing the **fullbase** of
   controller/action[/param1...] URL (be careful with the parameters
   btw) to the Session with `Auth.loginRedirect` name.

PS: Read [**jocull's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836990/how-to-get-complete-current-url-for-cakephp#comment11184149_6875310) to find out why I didn't use the `$this->here`.