# How to get complete current url for Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How do you echo out current URL in Cake's view?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can do either

From a view file:

```
<?php echo $this->request->here() ?>">
```

Which will give you the absolute url from the hostname i.e. /controller/action/params

Or

```
<?php echo Router::url(null, true) ?>
```

which should give you the full url with the hostname.

Comment: Side note from my experience (CakePHP 2+, not sure about the rest...) - you should use `Router::url(null, true)` instead of using `$this->here`. The reason is that if you ever have to configure a hardset base path $this->here will contain it already and your links will be double routed and broken. Just wanted to pass that along - confused the hell out of me tonight.

Comment: Also, in cake2.x `$this->here` would not be enough anymore. You would need to use `$this->here()` as this also appends the query string (and thus would then form the complete url).

Comment: @mark, what version are you on in 2.x? I'm in 2.4.5 and I get `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MyController::here()` when I try to use the `here()` method.

Comment: Probably $this->request->here() ;)

Comment: Please note that this doesn't contain the request URI

Comment: Personally I needed the URL without the base buth with any parameters passed to the controller. A way to solve that is using `$this->getRequest()->getUri()->getPath()` (CakePHP 3 and 4).

Answer (score 55):

I prefer this, because if I don't mention "request" word, my IDE gives warning.

```
<?php echo $this->request->here; ?>
```

API Document:
[class-CakeRequest](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeRequest.html#_here)

---

Edit:
To clarify all options

```
Current URL: http://example.com/en/controller/action/?query=12

// Router::url(null, true)
http://example.com/en/controller/action/

// Router::url(null, false)
/en/controller/action/

// $this->request->here
/en/controller/action/

// $this->request->here()
/en/controller/action/?query=12

// $this->request->here(false)
/en/controller/action/?query=12

// $this->request->url
en/controller/action

// $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
/en/controller/action/?query=12

// strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
/en/controller/action/
```

Comment: Thank you! You're a life saver.

Comment: My CakePHP project runs on the `localhost://projectname` URL (`projectname` folder in LAMPP stack), but using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` doesn't include the `prohjectname` part. Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 27):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]; ?>
```

EDIT: or,

```
<?php echo $this->Html->url( null, true ); ?>
```

Comment: There's no "Cake way" for everything that can be done simply with basic PHP :) I guess you could do `echo 
$this->Html->url( null, true );`

Answer (score 11):

The following "Cake way" is useful because you can grab the full current URL and modify parts of it without manually having to parse out the `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]` string and then manually concatenating it back into a valid url for output.

**Full current url:**
`Router::reverse($this->request, true)`

**Easily modifying specific parts of current url:**
1) make a copy of Cake's request object: 
`$request_copy = $this->request`

2) Then modify `$request_copy->params` and/or  `$request_copy->query` arrays

3) Finally: `$new_url = Router::reverse($request_copy, true)`.

Comment: Ooos, forgot the `true` parameter. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

Cakephp 3.5:

```
echo $this->Url->build($this->getRequest()->getRequestTarget());
```

Calling `$this->request->here()` is deprecated since 3.4, and will be removed in 4.0.0. You should use `getRequestTarget()` instead.
`$this->request` is also deprecated, `$this->getRequest()` should be used.

Comment: A comment on the accepted answer might have sufficed :)

Comment: Or `$this->getRequest()->getRequestTarget()`  to be even more deprecation-proof :D

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is a little dated, and CakePHP versions have flourished since. In the current (2.1.x) version of CakePHP and even in 1.3.x if I am not mistaken, one can get the current controller/view url like this:

```
$this->params['url'];
```

While this method does NOT return the parameters, it is handy if you want to append parameters to a link when building new URL's. For example, we have the current URL:

**projects/edit/6**

And we want to append a custom parameter action called c_action with a value of remove_image, one could make use of `$this->params['url];` and merge it with an array of custom parameter key => value pairs:

```
echo $this->Html->link('remove image', array_merge($this->params['url'], array('c_action' => 'remove_image'));
```

Using the above method we are able to append our custom parameters to the link and not cause a long chain on parameters to build up on the URL, because $this->params['url] only ever returns the controll action URL.

In the above example we'd need to manually add the ID of 6 back into the URL, so perahaps the final link build would be like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('remove image', array_merge($this->params['url'], array($id,'c_action' => 'remove_image'));
```

Where $is is a the ID of the project and you would have assigned it to the variable $id *at controller level*. The new URL will then be:

**projects/edit/6/c_action:remove_image**

Sorry if this is in the slightest unrelated, but I ran across this question when searching for a method to achieve the above and thought others may benefit from it.

Comment: You can just do `echo $this->Html->link('remove image', array('action' => 'remove_image'))`. I'm not sure if that is a functionality from later than 2.1.x, but that should work. Unless you overwrite the controller key in the array, the current controller will be used.

Comment: or `$this->request->url` for url including `query` and `named` params

Answer (score 5):

Getting the current URL is fairly straight forward in your view file

```
echo Router::url($this->here, true);
```

This will return the full url http://www.example.com/subpath/subpath

If you just want the relative path, use the following

```
echo $this->here;
```

**OR**

Ideally Router::url(“”, true) should return an absolute URL of the current view, but it always returns the relative URL. So the hack to get the absolute URL is

```
$absolute_url  = FULL_BASE_URL + Router::url(“”, false);
```

To get FULL_BASE_URL check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660262/1868660)

Answer (score 5):

for CakePHP 3:

```
$this->Url->build(null, true) // full URL with hostname

$this->Url->build(null) // /controller/action/params
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting current URL for CakePHP 3.x ?

In your layout :

```php
<?php 
    $here = $this->request->here();
    $canonical = $this->Url->build($here, true);
?>
```

You will get the full URL of the current page including query string parameters.

e.g. http://website.example/controller/action?param=value

You can use it in a meta tag canonical if you need to do some SEO.

```php
<link rel="canonical" href="<?= $canonical; ?>">
```

Comment: Note: here() has been deprecated as of CakePHP 3.4.0 in favor of getRequestTarget()

Answer (score 3):

In the request object you have everything you need. 
To understand it:

```
debug($this->request->url);
```

and in your case

```
$here = $this->request->url;
```

Comment: this one helped me out.. also that of "trante"

Answer (score 3):

To get the full URL without parameters:

```
echo $this->Html->url('/', true);
```

will return `http(s)://(www.)your-domain.com`

Answer (score 3):

After a few research, I got this as perfect **Full URL** for CakePHP 3.*

```
$this->request->getUri();
```

the **Full URL** will be something like this

> http://example.com/books/edit/12

More info you can read here: *https://pritomkumar.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-get-complete-current-url-for.html*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found is it that includes host/path/query and
works in `Controllers` (`Cakephp 3.4`):

```
Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper::build($this->request->getRequestTarget());
```

which returns something like this (we use it as login callback url) :

```
http://192.168.0.57/archive?melkId=12
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cake way for 1.3 is to use Router::reverse:

[Link to documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Router.html#_reverse)

```
$url = Router::reverse($this->params)
echo $url;
```

yields

```
/Full/Path/From/Root/MyController/MyAction/passed1/named_param:bob/?param1=true&param2=27
```

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp 3.x anywhere:

```
Router::reverse(Router::getRequest(),true)
```

Answer (score 1):

for CakePHP 3.x You can use `UrlHelper`:

```
$this->Url->build(null, true) // output http://somedomain.com/app-name/controller/action/params

$this->Url->build() // output /controller/action/params
```

Or you can use `PaginatorHelper` (in case you want to use it in javascript or ...):

```
$this->Paginator->generateUrl() // returns a full pagination URL without hostname

$this->Paginator->generateUrl([],null,true) // returns a full pagination URL with hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

for cakephp3+:

```
$url = $this->request->scheme().'://'.$this->request->domain().$this->request->here(false);
```

will get eg:
http://bgq.dev/home/index?t44=333

Answer (score 1):

**In View:**

```
Blank URL: <?php echo $this->Html->Url('/') ?>
Blank Full Url: <?php echo $this->Html->Url('/', true) ?>
Current URL: <?php echo $this->Html->Url($this->here) ?>
Current Full URL: <?php echo $this->Html->Url($this->here, true) ?>
```

**In Controller**

```
Blank URL: <?php echo Router::url('/') ?>
Blank Full Url: <?php echo Router::url('/', true) ?>
Current URL: <?php echo Router::url($this->request->here()) ?>
Current Full URL: <?php echo Router::url($this->request->here(), true) ?>
```

Comment: $this->Html->Url != $this->Html->url

Answer (score 0):

I use `$this->here` for the path, to get the whole URL you'll have to do as Juhana said and use the `$_SERVER` variables. There's no need to use a Cake function for this.

Answer (score 0):

All previously proposed approaches didn't satisfy my requirements for getting a complete URL (complete as in qualified) e.g. to be used in an email send from controller action. I need the scheme and hostname as well then, and thus stumbled over the following approach:

```php
<?php echo Router::url( array( $id ), true ) ?>
```

Due to providing router array current controller and action is kept, however id isn't and thus has to be provided here again. Second argument `true` is actually requesting to prepend hostname etc. for getting full URL.

Using Router::url() is available in every situation and thus can be used in view files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is easy FULL URL in Controler Work in CakePHP 1.3 >

```
<?php echo Router::url( array('controller'=>$this->params['controller'],'action'=>$this->params['action']), true );
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Use Html helper

```
<?php echo $this->Html->url($this->here, true); ?>
```

It'll produce the full url which'll started from http or https

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 `$this->here` will be deprecated. The actual way is using this method:

```
Router::url($this->request->getRequestTarget())
```

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 4.*

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Dashboard',
    ['controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'index', '_full' => true]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the base path, you can check that the `Router` class is using `Configure::read ('App.fullBaseUrl')`. So if you are a fan of hexagonal architecture, you can create a Cake implementation for creating URLs that will only use `Configure` from all CakePHP framework.