# PHP: send and get a url in the get variable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In My application after successful login in index page, I want to redirect the page(whatever in goto variable)

Take an example I want to get `page1.php?name=ss&age=75` as goto variable.

```
www.example.com/index.php?goto=page1.php?name=ss&age=75
```

But I got only `page1.php?name=ss` from `$_REQUEST['goto']`

Please provide me the best way to get whole url

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836990/how-to-get-complete-current-url-for-cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all & by @ symbol in url goto variable like `page1.php@name=ss@age=45`

and replace all @ symbol by & in the received goto variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) your variable, doing `urlencode('page1.php?name=ss&age=75')` will give you `page1.php%3Fname%3Dss%26age%3D75` which you can plug to the query string without it being misinterpret.

Answer (score 0):

`www.example.com/index.php?goto=page1.php?name=ss&age=75` is not a valid URL. It contains two `?` for instance.

You will have to pass the `goto` parameter around some other way. You could base64 encode it before you put it into a URL, and then base64 decode it once you need it to redirect the user.

Or you could simply url encode/decode it.

Comment: You don't even need to urldecode it, that happens automatically.. All you need to do is urlencode it when you plug it to your query string, and it'll have the correct value on PHP's side.