# Method in Controller to get current url

Tags: cakephp

As the title, I want to ask is there a method in Controller to get current url in CakePHP ?

Or I have to do this in View then pass it ass parameter to Controller ?

Please help me out :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the current relative URL in either your view or your controller, you can do this:

```
<?php echo $this->here; ?>
```

If you want to get the full URL in your controller, including domain, do this:

```
<?php echo Router::url( $this->here, true ); ?>
```

You won't be able to pass anything from your view back to your controller - that's not how MVC works.

Almost the exact same question is asked here: [How to get complete current url for Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836990/how-to-get-complete-current-url-for-cakephp)

Comment: In CakePHP 3, you xcan use $this->request->here(true);